# Stop session prolongation in Spring project

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

`web.xml` contain:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Spring `security-context.xml` have custom OAuth 2.0 authorisation filter:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
          entry-point-ref="oauthEntryPoint"
          authentication-manager-ref="oauthAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
    ...
</sec:http>
```

As longer session valid `attemptAuthentication` method of `myFilter` was not called. If session expired `attemptAuthentication` method make request to REST API of custom OAuth 2.0 server to verify OAuth token validity (then redirect to login page or prolong session).

Session have 30 min timeout, OAuth token have 1 day timeout.

If user keep activity during 30 min - session automatically extended and user can be logged-in for many days when OAuth token become invalid!

How to invalidate session from first login access not from the time of last site access?

**UPDATE** Look also to my question on http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/725894-help-with-stoping-sesstion-prolongation

I read Servlet 2.1 specification. Seems that session is managed by container which provide Servlet API. It have session timeout to avoid memory overload from old inactive sessions.

So you have no control on session expiring. To achive my goal I can associate special *creation timestamp* with session and check it for expiring.

But as  Will Keeling say this info already stored in `session`:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if (session == null)
    logger.warn("session is null");
  else
    logger.warn("session created at {}", session.getCreationTime());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly implement your own servlet filter which checks the session creation time and then invalidates the session if it is accessed after the fixed time period.

```
long oneDay = 86400000;
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getCreationTime()) > oneDay) {
    session.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime%28%29